# R equivalent of python "_"?

Tags: python, r, ipython

Python has an identifier `_` that allows for storing the result of the [last evaluation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) which makes it great for speeding up data exploration and introspection.

```
In [1]: 43 * 2
Out[1]: 86

In [2]: _ + 1
Out[2]: 87
```

Is there a similar command in R?

Comment: @David - For what it's worth, the standard python interpreter does the same thing when used interactively.  It's not just ipython.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers toward the bottom of the section: "In interactive mode, the last printed expression is assigned to the variable _."

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Tis a faff to type, but .Last.value:

```
> sqrt(2)
[1] 1.414214
> .Last.value
[1] 1.414214
```

Comment: I agree that the name is difficult to remember. You could do this:`.Last()
function() (return(.Last.value)); 
 a <- 3`
#> .Last()
[1] 3

Comment: Try this: makeActiveBinding(".",function() .Last.value,env=.GlobalEnv) then "." is the value, similar to "_".