# Shorthand for .Last.value in R?

Tags: r

The [.Last.value](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Last.value.html) command in R is useful for quick calculations, but the name is pretty long and difficult to write (probably because `.Last.value` should not be overwritten). Therefore, it is often faster to copy-paste the number from line above.

```
124/pi
# [1] 39.47043
.Last.value^2
# [1] 1557.915
```

I know that it is possible to do [partial matching for functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153904/partial-matching-of-function-argument), but for `.Last.value` this does not seem to work:

```
1+1
# [1] 2
.Last.v + 1
# Error: object '.Last.v' not found
```

Is there a handier (shorter/faster/better) way to draw the last value from R console?

Comment: Create a function like `LV <- function() .Last.value`? Then call it with `LV()` when required?

Comment: The classic answer to this is Verzani's comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973185/r-equivalent-of-python/4973224#comment5564251_4973224

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a closure to capture this and put it in your .Rprofile. For example:

```
lv = function () .Last.value
```

And then call `lv()` wherever you need to use .Last.value. Hopefully, you only use it in interactive mode and nowhere in scripting.

Comment: Hah! @Ananda and I answered at almost the same time.

Comment: +1 for the same idea then :-)

Comment: If four symbols is too long it is possible to make active binding: makeActiveBinding("a", lv, .GlobalEnv)  After that just type "a" to see last value.

Comment: @asb This is the best solution until the R-studio team comes up with a quick double tap of up arrow to do the same trick or something =) Btw, I get your meaning, but the code does not work as it is. Cannot assign functions to `()`. Could you fix your answer to `lv <- function() .Last.value`?

Comment: @Largh: Apologies. That was stupid.

Comment: I use `makeActiveBinding(".", function() .Last.value, env = globalenv())` so I can use `.` like Ruby and Python use `_`.