# Applying a function to the last result in R with minimal typing

Tags: r, read-eval-print-loop

On [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Bootvis/status/1212737762916478980) I asked the following:

> In RStudio, is there an easy way to pipe the last result stored in
>   `.Last.value` into a function. Say I did:
>
> `tbl <- CreateTable(x)`.
>
> I now want to do `View(tbl)` but with less typing. Just type
>
> `.View`
>
> or something. Is that possible? #rstats #rstudio

Is there maybe a general way to do this?

Comment: You can directly click on the object `tbl` which would get listed under `Environment` tab in Rstudio/

Comment: I want it to be a general function, not just `View()`. For `View()` you can also use [F2](https://twitter.com/jozefhajnala/status/1212757997782536193).

Comment: might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588816/shorthand-for-last-value-in-r

Comment: A Twitter user gave a solution: https://twitter.com/antoine_fabri/status/1213049033553588224

Comment: So .Last.value works, really cool maybe you can reassign with a function to a shorter name or make a shortcut for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few ways, this is all strange stuff so I hope you'll keep it for interactive use, won't put anything in your RProfile and won't share code using those :).

**1 - create a binding for `.`**

`.` will be a shortcut for `.Last.Value`, saving most of the typing.
*magrittr* pipes and functional sequences will still work, and so will *purrr* lambdas.

```
makeActiveBinding(".", function() .Last.value, .GlobalEnv)
4
sqrt(.) # 2
```

If you have a `µ`, a `λ` or another compliant special character easily accessible on your keyboard it might be a good idea to use it instead.

**2 - hacking `print.function`**

We can hack `print.function` so it runs the function on the last value.

Here I couldn't use `.Last.value` because it's the value of the function itself, so I need to re-execute the previous call, so in some cases it might be slow.

```
print.function <- function(x){
  tf <- tempfile()
  savehistory(tf)
  last_calls <- parse(text=tail(readLines(tf),2))
  if(as.list(last_calls[[2]])[[1]] == quote(print))
    base:::print.function(x) else print(x(eval.parent(last_calls[[1]])))
}
4
sqrt # 2
4
print(sqrt) # the actual definition
```

**3 - Use package doubt**

We can build a dubious operator that will use `.Last.value` :

```
# remotes::install_github("moodymudskipper/doubt")
library(doubt)
`?+{fun}` <- function(fun){ fun(.Last.value)}
4
?+sqrt # 2
```

**4 - give a class to the functions you care about**

And define a method for an unary operator (`+`, `-`, and `!` will all work) :

```
class(sqrt) <- class(summary) <- class(View) <- "magic_function"
`+.magic_function` <- function(fun){ fun(.Last.value)}
4
+sqrt # 2
```

Comment: Really nice suggestions, thanks. 4 is my current favourite.